# Do I create multiple implementations of a repository to adhere to open/closed principle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, solid-principles

I could be completely off with this, as the open/closed principle is the main bit of SOLID that I don't quite get. Basically, I have a parameter that I pass from a controller to a service.  That service gets certain information from a repository based on that parameter. For example:

```
switch(param){
    case "date": 
        _repository.GetByDate(date);
        break;
    case "serialNumber": 
        _repository.GetBySerialNumber(number);
        break;
}
```

These repositories are based on abstractions. My question is, should I be somehow creating multiple repositories for this, and how would I go about that? I don't see anyone adding a new option anytime soon, but it could be possible in the future. Or do I keep this as a switch statement, and then build a Func<> based on the property so I only have to have one implementation in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options:

1. If these are different types, then you can simply use overloads and feed it whatever you've got:

   ```
   public Foo Get(DateTime date)

   public Foo Get(int number)
   ```

   Then, you'd just pass in whatever:

   ```
   _repository.Get(lookupValue);
   ```
2. Just move the switch into the repo, which will handle more generic scenarios, including when there's different lookups for the same type (i.e. string):

   ```
   public Foo Get<T>(string lookupType, T lookupValue)
   {
       switch (lookupType){
           case "date": 
               GetByDate(lookupValue);
               break;
           case "serialNumber": 
               GetBySerialNumber(lookupValue);
               break;
        }
   }
   ```

Both of these assume you can somehow pass the lookup value generically. If you're literally ending up with physical `date` and `number` variables, and you don't know which to pass in, then you're kind of stuck with the switch in your action, unless you create some sort of helper object to ferry them in to the repo method:

```
public class FooLookup
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public Foo Get(FooLookup lookup)
{
    switch (lookup.Type){
        case "date": 
            GetByDate(lookup.Date);
            break;
        case "serialNumber": 
            GetBySerialNumber(lookup.Number);
            break;
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
_repository.Get(new FooLookup
{
    Type = param,
    Date = date,
    Number = number
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory the `switch` does not violate the OCP as long as you can subclass the service to override that method. That way the code remains open for extension without requiring modification. In practice most developers are unlikely to follow that approach and would instead violate the OCP by editing the `switch` to add a new `case`.

Since the repository already exposes its various getters as separate methods, why not expose the exact same method signatures through the service?

Comment: Because I have to make the distinction somewhere about which method is being called, and I'd rather not have that logic in my controller.  The method in the service with the switch receives a Tuple that holds the 'parameters'.